# Converting a Boost actor_lexer to static: Error as if "actor_" not used

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-lex

I'm converting a Boost Spirit Lex program to the [static lexer model](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/lex/abstracts/lexer_static_model.html). The lexer has a semantic action, therefore the dynamic lexer is of type `actor_lexer`:

```
#ifndef USE_STATIC_SI_LEXER
    typedef lex::lexertl::actor_lexer<token_type> lexer_type;
#else
    typedef lex::lexertl::static_lexer<
        token_type,
        lex::lexertl::static_::lexer_si
    > lexer_type;
#endif
```

Now when compiling with the static lexer, I get the error

```
boost/spirit/home/lex/lexer/lexertl/static_lexer.hpp(230): 
error C2039: 'add_action' : is not a member of 'boost::spirit::unused_type'
```

which is exactly what is expected when one uses a semantic action but forgets to change `lexer` into `actor_lexer`. I did use the `actor_lexer` type in the generator program, which seems to work as far as I can tell.

Is there something else I'm missing? Or is it currently impossible to use semantic actions in a static lexer?

Comment: https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/develop/example/lex/static_lexer/word_count_lexer_static.cpp#L59 ?

Comment: @llonesmiz nailed it

Comment: @llonesmiz YES! this did it. Please make it an answer. (This should really be on the page I linked, though.)

Comment: @FelixDombek I'm certain you could make a better answer than me(please do), I just looked at the examples and found that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `static_actor_lexer` template for use in this case, as seen in [this example](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/develop/example/lex/static_lexer/word_count_lexer_static.cpp#L59).

```
lex::lexertl::static_actor_lexer<
    token_type, lex::lexertl::static_::lexer_wcl
>
```